# Jquery - Need help using Captcha

Tags: jquery, validation

Can anynone tell me how to write a custom validator for the below captcha code? I am new to jquery and havent wrote any custom validator. I need to use this custom validator along with the default validators. I tried writing but it didnt work. Please help

```
challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
var html = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "recaptcharesponse.jsp",
data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" +     responseField,
async: false
}).responseText;
//console.log( html );
$("#prtCnt").html("");
return true;
} else {
$("#prtCnt").html("<font color='#D31145'>Please try again.The characters you entered     didn't match the word verification</font>");   
Recaptcha.reload();                                         
return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This post title is very misleading

Answer (score 0):

```
        challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
        responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "recaptcharesponse.jsp",
data: {"recaptcha_challenge_field" :challengeField,"recaptcha_response_field":responseField),
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg == "something from server that captcha is ok"){
              //catcha is ok do wat you want
            }else{
            $("#prtCnt").html("<font color='#D31145'>Please try again.The characters you  entered  didn't match the word verification</font>");   
        Recaptcha.reload();
    }

    },error:function(){


    }

        });
```

Comment: BTW the html attribute font is depreciated use span or something else

Comment: Thank a lot. Do I need to put this code in the document.ready? How make this workable when the submit button is clicked. Please advise

Comment: I added this code to the submit button click event and the validation works but the validation for other fields doesn't work.

Comment: Other filed validation  is not coded here or in your question..if you want that do it in your ajax success function

Comment: The other field validation is already done with the rules & messages. When I add this click event the validation for captucha only works other field doesn't work. If I remove the click event the other form fields validation works. How Do i make it both work?

Comment: get that rules and checking inside the ajax success function..hope you got it..else comment here .ill update the code

Comment: Those are global rules which are written inside jsforminit.js. on the form when i use the click event on the submit button the global rules & messages doesnt work.

Comment: Any method to call the default validation that happens in the submit event?